# JSPDF output() do not show image

Tags: javascript, jspdf

hi im using jspdf to create pdf file. i want to convert that into base64 and save it in the server. im using output method for that.

```
var output = doc.output()
var url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + Base64.encode(output);
```

the problem in this scenario is that images are not showing in the pdf. 
if i use    **doc.output('datauri')** then it shows the images but it will open a new window. without opening the pdf, how can i get the pdf content with images to Base64

these are the script i have used

```
<script src="js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="js/base64.js"></script>
<script src="js/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

found a solution

```
 var output = doc.output('datauristring') 
// var url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + Base64.encode(output);
```

**'datauristring'** returns the base64 encoded output. so no need to convert it again using base64 method.